# CSS - Why you can't use decimal number to represent percentage for Saturation or Lightness in HSL?

Tags: css, colors, hsl

I can use either 50% or 0.5 to represent opacity, and they all works

hsla(x, x, x, 0.5) or hsla (x, x, x, 50%)

but not for Saturation and Lightness

hsla(x, 50%, x, x) would work, hsla (x, 0.5, x, x) won't work

Why? Is using decimal numbers conflicts with other functions? Why does the syntax not let this representation of percentage?

Comment: because this is how the syntax was defined

Comment: Is using decimal numbers conflicts with other functions?

Comment: added more duplicates

Comment: then why can Alpha input work either way?

Comment: it was simply defined that way. There is no random behavior, each value is defined in a precise way

Comment: I just want to know why it is defined this way, is that very high-level knowledge I should not get in touch now?

Comment: you can discuss with people that do such definitions: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts